# Python and PHP use the same mySQL database

Tags: php, python, mysql, wamp

I have a script in Python that retrieves data from a remote server into a MySQL database located on my computer (the one that runs the Python script).

This script is executed daily to retrieve fresh data into the MySQL database. I am using Workbench 6.0 for Windows 64.

I want to add a web GUI to the system that will present some of the data on a web page. I would like to write it in PHP and for my PHP program to use the same MySQL database that my Python script uses. I would like to make it a web server later on so users can log in to the sever and use this web GUI.

Can the PHP and the Python scripts use the same DB?

In the past I have worked with WAMP sever for PHP only. If I install WAMP on the sever, will it be able to use the same DB or can it cause a collision?

Comment: Sure they can. A DBMS does not restrict the number and the nature of the clients interacting with it.

Comment: OK thanks. I installed WAMP but it is pending and not starting. The reason for that, as far as i understand is: WAMP comes with mysql DB and I already have a mysql DB on my computer (on port 3306). The new DB probably listens on the same port. How can I solve this?

Comment: sounds like you are familiar with python already but not with PHP. So why not just use python for the whole thing? Something like Django would make this really easy

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment, but I don't have enough rep. yet.  You should be able to start the Apache and PHP services separately from the WAMP tray icon.  If you can't, try this:

You should be able to use the WAMP menu on the tray icon to open WAMP's `my.ini` file.  In there, just change the port number from 3306 to something else (might as well use 3307) and save the file, then restart WAMP.  In the future, completely ignore WAMP's MySQL instance and just use the one that Python is connecting to.

If that still doesn't work, you might have Skype running.  By default, Skype listens on Port 80 for some bizarre reason.  Open Skype's settings, go to the "Connection" section and untick "Use port 80 as an alternative for incoming connections."  Then try restarting WAMP again.